# Button link display in shortcodes using custom field in ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I used the ACF plugin to display custom post type( history ) there I add a custom field for button and button link. Now I create a shortcode of history post type but I don't know how I can add button link that I used in custom fied please solve this 
here my code :

```
add_shortcode( 'history_shortcodes', 'history_shortcodes_post_type' );
    function history_shortcodes_post_type(){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'history',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        $string = '';
        $h_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $h_query->have_posts() ){
            $string .= '<div class="main_history">';
            while( $h_query->have_posts() ){
                $h_query->the_post();

                $h_button_field = get_field('history_button_title'); // used to display the custom field 
                if( !empty($h_button_field) ): endif;
                $h_link = get_field('history_button_url'); // used to display the custom field 
                if( $h_link ):  endif;

                $string .= '<div class="col-sm-6">' . '<div class="single_history_img">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>' . '</div>' . '<div class="col-sm-6">' . '<div class="single_history_content">' . '<div class="head_title">' . '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>' . '</div>' . '<p>' . get_the_content() . '</p>' . '<a href="" class="btn btn-lg">' . $h_button_field . '</a>' . '</div>' . '</div>';

            }
            $string .= '</div>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $string;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why can't you get `$h_link` in your anchor tag..


Can you please first vardump the value of `$h_button_field` and `$h_link`

Comment: I try to add this in anchor tag 
'<a href="$h_link" class="btn btn-lg">'
but it not working, i dont know the right way to add this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I have recorrected your code, if you have successfully retrieved those two variables

```
 $string = '';
$h_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $h_query->have_posts() ){
    $string .= '<div class="main_history">';
    while( $h_query->have_posts() ){
        $h_query->the_post();

        $h_button_field = get_field('history_button_title'); // used to display the custom field 
        if( !empty($h_button_field) ): endif;
        $h_link = get_field('history_button_url'); // used to display the custom field 
        if( $h_link ):  endif;

        $string .= '<div class="col-sm-6">' . '<div class="single_history_img">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>' . '</div>' . '<div class="col-sm-6">' . '<div class="single_history_content">' . '<div class="head_title">' . '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>' . '</div>' . '<p>' . get_the_content() . '</p>' . '<a href="'.$h_link.'" class="btn btn-lg">' . $h_button_field . '</a>' . '</div>' . '</div>';

    }
    $string .= '</div>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
return $string;
```

}

Comment: Oh wow its working, Thank you so much sir for this.

Comment: Can you please that as correct an upvote the answer

Comment: I upvote this sir